# Angular - subscribe data to observable returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, observable, subscribe

I'm working on an Angular project. but I have problem when I subscribe the data to observable is returning undefined

and I have a service method that returns data from HTTP.

```
public serviceMethod(): Observable<WordList[]> {
const url = `${this.baseUrl}/wordLists`;

   return this.httpClient.get<GetResponseWordList>(url).pipe(
      map(response => response._embedded.wordLists)

   );
}
```

and a component method that takes the data from the service and assigns it to an **"array"**

```
  componentMethod() {

  // get from the service
  this.otherService.serviceMethod().subscribe(
    data => {
      this.array = data;


    }
  );

}
```

I have another method in the same file that use the **"array"**

```
secondMethod(){
    console.log(this.array)
}
```

Finally, I have the main method that uses both the last two methods.

```
 mainMethodMethod(){
    componentMethod();
    secondMethod();
}
```

the componentMethod() is run first. However, always get an **"undefined"** value of the array

one solution is to put the secondMethod() inside componentMethod() when to subscribe the data. But I don't want to do that because I need to use a loop and that will take too long.

Comment: You must call `secondMethod()` asynchronously. That means as a matter of the `complete` handler of the `subscribe()` within `componentMethod()` or have `componentMethod()` return something async (a promise or Observable).

Comment: 1. make a console.log directly at service and check if you are retreiving data. 
(here response._embedded.wordLists)

2. open network tab check the request

Comment: If you show the loop, we probably will be able to give more appropriate answers. As far as I understand, you don't want to make the second method await for the component method to return the data, so maybe we can split the part which uses the data from other, which can run without it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your secondMethod in the subscribe function after the data variable.

It gets undefined since its asynchronous, it has to wait for the data to finish loading then call your next functions.

If you call it after the first method then the 2nd method will get executed without the first

Comment: I know, I'm asking to get another solution

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should clarify this part of your question :

> "But I don't want to do that because I need to use a loop and that will take too long"

What is the loop you need to use ?
Because it's constraint that is maybe the base of the problem ...

With what you explained, I see (at least) this solution :

```
componentMethod() {
  // get from the service
  return this.otherService.serviceMethod().pipe(
    map(data => {
      this.array = data;
    })
  );
}

mainMethodMethod(){
    componentMethod().subscribe(() => {
        secondMethod();
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `tap` instead of `map` because you really do not map anything here and don't use the calculated result

Comment: You're right Alexey !!